# I don't have any firebase dependencies. But app crashes with firebase error

Tags: android, google-play-services

I don't have any firebase dependencies in my project. But app crashes with following error in console.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zza(Landroid/app/Application;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbav; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbav' appears in /data/app/com.justhive-1/base.apk)
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here is my app.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I really can't understand where firebase dependencies come from.

Comment: Either from play-services-base and/or play-services-gcm.

Comment: If so, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: It appears to be an internal issue, where/when does it happen?

Comment: It happens when I launch the app.

Comment: Then I dont know if there is anything you can do, update to the latest GPS `11.0.2` and see if that fixes it try removing one of those references and see if its works so you know what breaking it if not maybe move to FCM since GCM is no longer used